# UDM PRO VPN and different VLANS

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, unifi

I'm running a UDM Pro with 3 USW24-POE which are connected via fibre (OS2) which is running fine meanwhile.

On the UDM there are a few VLANS which are all managed by the UDM Pro.
The Main Lan is `192.168.10.0/24` which is my "tech" Lan, then there is a "facility" lan `192.168.5.0/24 with Vlan-ID of 2` and a "gastronomy" lan `172.168.16.0/24 with Vlan-ID 60`.

I'm trying to get a VPN connection directly over the Windows VPN. The VPN Server is configurated correctly and authenticates via RADIUS with a subnet of `192.168.70.0/24`.

The main problem is, that if I am connected with VPN I can reach every client which is in the `192.168.10.0/24` range but no others. I'd like to reach the clients in the `192.168.5.0/24` and the only thing I can ping is the DHCP Server (`192.168.5.1`).

The problem exists only when using L2TP, when using wireguard everything works fine (the bad thing is that my client wants to use the built-in Windows VPN).

I also tried to configure the radius server to "Assigned Vlan Support" Wired and Wireless enabled with the Vlan-ID 2 set on the user which doesn't do the trick. And I also tried to route the IP Range from `192.168.70.1 - 192.168.70.255` to the `192.168.5.0/24` network...

Could someone please tell me which configuration part I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem is solved meanwhile. It was a Misconfiguration of third-party because they didn't setup the Gateway. As nearby everywhere is described the VPN is open for all Networks in the Unifi Network until you close the conection with trafficmanagement or the firewall.